# reading the maze file and print it

Tags: java, bufferedreader, maze

This program is about maze recursion and I'm struggling finding out how to read the maze file and print the solved maze since I'm new in Java. Could anyone explain it to me how to call the print method from main method? Thank you in advance!

```
public class Maze {

    private static char[][] maze;
    private static int rows = 0;
    private static int columns = 0;


    public Maze(char[][] mazeIn) {
        maze = mazeIn;
    }

    private static boolean valid (int r, int c) {

          boolean result = false;

          // check if cell is in the bounds of the matrix
          if (r >= 0 && r < maze.length &&
              c >= 0 && c < maze[0].length)

             //  check if cell is not blocked and not previously tried
             if (maze[r][c] == '1')
                result = true;

          return result;

       }  // method valid

    public static boolean solve (int r, int c) {

          boolean done = false;

          if (valid (r, c)) {

             maze[r][c] = '7';  // cell has been tried

             if (r == maze.length-1 && c == maze[0].length-1)
                done = true;  // maze is solved
             else {
                done = solve (r+1, c);  // down
                if (!done)
                   done = solve (r, c+1);  // right
                if (!done)
                   done = solve (r-1, c);  // up
                if (!done)
                   done = solve (r, c-1);  // left
             }
             if (done)  // part of the final path
                maze[r][c] = '8';
          }

          return done;

       }  // method solve

    public static void print () {

          System.out.println();

          for (int r=0; r < maze.length; r++) {
             for (int c=0; c < maze[r].length; c++)
                System.out.print (maze[r][c]);
             System.out.println();
          }

          System.out.println();

       }  // method print_maze


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

      String fileName = "Maze.txt";

      try {
            String readline;

            FileReader fileReader = 
                    new FileReader(fileName);

                BufferedReader br = 
                    new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                int line = 0;
                while((readline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(readline); //loads the maze

                char[] charArr = readline.toCharArray();
                maze[line] = charArr;  // error here

                line++;
                }

        br.close();         
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file '" + 
            fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + fileName + "'");                  

        }
    }
}
```

the maze.txt file looks like this

```
 000100000000000  
 000100001000010  
 000111111111000   
 000100000001000  
 000111110001000  
 000000010001000  
 000011110001000  
 000010010001010  
 000010010000000  
 000010000000000  
 000011111110000  
 000000000010000  
 000000000010000  
 000001000011110  
 000000000010000
```

Comment: you're code is fine, just a typo, change `"Mazes.txt"` to `"maze.txt"` works for me.

Comment: silly me lol yeah, I fixed it but it doesn't print like I want to for example all the 1s should change to 8(path) and or 7( if the cell has been tried). @downshift

Comment: Oh I see, ok, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I would do differently, but the important part is that you're not populating the char array with any data.  While you're reading in the data, you need to populate it into the char array.  Something like this would work:

```
 int line = 0;
 while((readline = br.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(readline); //loads the maze
     char[] charArr = readline.toCharArray();
     maze[line] = charArr;
     line++;
 }
```

Additionally, the maze array is never actually instantiated, and the main method is never calling "solve()" or "print()".  These are things you can handle in your main method.

Finally, if you're going to call "solve()," you have to decide whether you want to instantiate an instance of the Maze class and call solve on that (which would involve quite a bit of code changes, but is the right approach), or else "solve()" should be a static method as well, which means "valid()" also has to be static.

P.S.: you have an error in your for-loop

```
for (int c=0; columns < maze[r].length; c++)
```

You should just change "columns" to "c".

P.P.S., in your solve method you're assigning ints to a char array.  Put 7 and 8 in single-quotes to indicate that they're chars, not ints.

```
 maze[r][c] = '7';  // cell has been tried
```

This is especially important in your valid() method, because you're testing if the maze[r][c]==1, but you should be testing if maze[r][c]=='1'.

I made all these changes myself and got this as output

```
 000700000000000  
 000700007000010  
 000777777777000   
 000700000007000  
 000777770007000  
 000000070007000  
 000077770007000  
 000070070007010  
 000070070000000  
 000070000000000  
 000077777770000  
 000000000070000  
 000000000070000  
 000001000077770  
 000000000070000
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and I did everything like you said but I got this error        000100000000000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Maze.main(Maze.java:332)     do you have any idea what does that mean? I know I have to put null somewhere but I can't find it. @RaceYouAnytime

Comment: @Daniel I don't know what part of the code that is.  What's on line 332 and the lines around it?  Also, how did you instantiate the array?

Comment: Ok I fixed the code but I'm having trouble how to call the solve() or print() method properly, can you explain it for me please? Also, I got a different error        000100000000000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at Maze.main(Maze.java:99)       @RaceYouAnytime

Comment: int line = 0;
             maze = new char[rows][columns];
             while((readline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 System.out.println(readline); //loads the maze
                 
                 char[] charArr = readline.toCharArray();
                 for(int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++){
                 maze[i][line] = charArr[i];  // line 99 error here
                 }
                 line++;
                 
             }
            
     br.close();         
    }

Comment: @Daniel it looks like you didn't allocate enough rows, or columns, or that you mixed up the two.  Also be careful because there might be blank spaces that end up in your char array.  That's why I just wrote:                     char[] charArr = readline.toCharArray(); maze[line] = charArr; line++;

Comment: @Daniel if you update the code in your question with the latest code, I can take another look.

Comment: Oh okay got it! Just updated the code. I know I haven't instantiated the arrays, I looked up the tutorials to learn how to instantiate but I can't figure out, could you explain to me? @RaceYouAnytime

Comment: @Daniel you're almost there, all you have to do is change the first line in the class to **private static char[][] maze = new char[20][20];** and at the end of your "main" method, add **solve(0,4); print();**  The only thing I would say apart from that is that right now your algorithm doesn't work for setting the final path to 8's.  For that you'll need to take a look at the "solve" method and think carefully about what it's doing.  But if you make the two changes above, you'll at least see 7's like in the output I put in my answer, and you'll be on the right track.

Comment: Sweet! Yeah I have to make some changes in the solve method. Thank you for your help! Appreciate it! @RaceYouAnytime

Comment: @Daniel glad to help, feel free to upvote / accept the answer if it helped you :)